# Is it possible to fill the textfield with OTP without user interaction in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to implement an OTP feature in an app.

I know that Apple provides a feature called "oneTimeCode" for textContentType for text field but it needs the user to select to paste on the text field.

```
field.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

I like to fill the OTP text field without user interaction in 6 separate text fields.

Answer (score 0):

[AutoFill UI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view) is necessary and it is managed by OS, so you cannot override this behavior.